# How to handle device orientation on multiple view in IOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, orientation

I am developing an application in which I have two ViewControllers names as VC1 and VC2, VC1 should support both portrait and landscape orientation means in portrait it should show map and in landscape it should show list. Now for VC2 it works only in portrait mode.
I am attaching images for both ViewControllers
[image]

[image]

in second image Google map should be in portrait and list in landscape but when I change orientation from portrait to landscape list is generate only in portrait mode.below is the code to handle orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your rootViewController is `UINavigationController` then you need to use category of `UINavigationController`. such like

**UINavigationController+autoRotate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationController (autoRotate)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;

@end
```

**UINavigationController+autoRotate.m**

```
#import "UINavigationController+autoRotate.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (autoRotate)

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

@end
```

And then use following method in your **viewController.**

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UIInterfaceOrientation Methods

// for iOS 6 and latter
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    // return as you want;
    return YES;
}

// for iOS 5 and lower
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // return as you want;
    return  YES;
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //UIInterfaceOrientationMask as you want 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `UINavigationController` in your app `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` will not get called in your ViewControllers. In that case you have to subclass `UINavigationController`.

```
@interface RotationAwareNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

@implementation RotationAwareNavigationController

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIViewController *top = self.topViewController;
    return top.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    UIViewController *top = self.topViewController;
    return [top shouldAutorotate];
}

@end
```